# What makes admin button pop up on open graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have an open graph page:

http://www.pmctool.com/pmc-extravaganza.php

I have my fb_userID in the fb_admin og meta tag, but it never shows me the Admin button for the page. I created other pages with the same code, and I have an admin button that shows up, but this page I cannot get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doing it in the correct order.

1. "unlike" the page
2. run through the linter (just to be sure the page is rescraped by facebook)
   http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
3. F5 - refresh the page
4. "like" the page
5. F5 - refresh
6. You should now see the admin link!

If that doesn't work. Rerun the linter and wait 10-15 minutes to make sure the information propogates in facebook's servers, then redo the above steps (skipping #2)

If fb_admins has your userID, all should go well.